# Target class [app\Http\Controller\SocialController] does not exist.(when pressed on login with facebook )

Tags: php, laravel

[image]

```
Target class [app\Http\Controller\SocialController] does not exist.
```

when pressed on login with Facebook shown this error

my code is  social controller and after press on login with face book button show me this upper error

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Laravel\socialite\Facades\Socialite;

class SocialController extends Controller
{
    public function redirect($service)
    {
        return socialite::driver($service)->redirect();
    }
    
    public function callback($service)
    {
        return $user=socialite::with($service)->user();
    }
}
```

my web page  code is

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controller\SocialController;

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
Route::get('redirect/{service}',[SocialController::class,'redirect']);
Route::get('callback/{service}',[SocialController::class,'callback']);
```

Comment: The namespace of your `SocialController` is `App\Http\Controllers`. But in your routes file you use `use App\Http\Controller\SocialController;` , which is missing the `s` in Controller**s**

Answer (score 0):

You missed **`s`** in Controllers in `web.php` file. Correctly written would be:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\SocialController;
```